# Laravel not able to route to controller

Tags: laravel, controller, routes, composer-php, laravel-artisan

Here is my controller class:

```
class CallrequestController extends BaseController {

    public function getIndex()
    {
        return View::make('results');
    }

}
```

which is saved in:

```
--app
  --controllers
    --CallrequestController.php
```

then I autoloaded via composer:
`composer dump-autoload`

then i add the route to route file:

```
Route::controller('getrequest','CallrequestController');
```

here is the registered route via php artisan routes:

```
+--------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+------+-------------------------------------+----------------+---------------+
| Domain | URI                                                               | Name | Action                              | Before Filters | After Filters |
+--------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+------+-------------------------------------+----------------+---------------+
|        | GET|HEAD /                                                        |      | Closure                             |                |               |
|        | GET|HEAD callrequest/index/{one?}/{two?}/{three?}/{four?}/{five?} |      | CallrequestController@getIndex      |                |               |
|        | GET|HEAD callrequest                                              |      | CallrequestController@getIndex      |                |               |
|        | GET|HEAD|POST|PUT|PATCH|DELETE callrequest/{_missing}             |      | CallrequestController@missingMethod |                |               |
+--------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+------+-------------------------------------+----------------+---------------+
```

yet its not routing to the controller, i get the default "Whoops, looks like something went wrong." error message.

what am i doing wrong?

*edit* also here is a sample url:

```
mydomainname.com/getrequest
```

Comment: are you already try just use `public function getIndex() { return "Test Index"; }` ?

Comment: @rasah_dipikir_jerojero yea ur right the error was in the method, but its still odd how laravel doesn't show php errors...

Comment: go to `app/config` open `app.php` change `'debug' => false,` to `'debug' => true`, (around line 16)